# cat file to udp, pt 2: send 1 udp packet per ^C-delimited line

Tags: bash, cat, netcat, multicast

Yesterday I asked [a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111539/19581) about catting a file over a UDP socket in bash.

The solution we came up was `netcat -c -w 1 -v -u -s 127.0.0.1 239.255.0.1 30001 < test.txt`.  This worked in the sense that it sent the packets, but there's a problem.

The source file isn't strictly a text file.  It's actually a binary file  -- the content is mostly text, with embedded non-printable characters and no `\n` lineendings.  Instead, the control character `^C` (0x03) is used as a line delimiter.

When `netcat` was sending packets, it would send as much as possible in a single UDP frame.  But I want it to send one UDP frame per `^C`-delimited mesasge in the source file.

For example, if my file consists of:

```
foo^Cbar^Cbaz^C
```

using `netcat` would result in one UDP frame being sent.  What I want is to send 3 messages:

1. `foo^C`
2. `bar^C`
3. `baz^C`

Is there a way to accomplish this?

---

I have tried a number of possible solutions, but nothing's worked.

For one I've tried `sed`ding the source file to replace the `^C` with `^C\n`, but that had no effect:

```
sed 's/^C/^C\n\0/g' test.txt  | netcat -n -vv -c -w 1 -v -u -s 127.0.0.1 239.255.0.2 30002
```

I also tried catting the files to `/dev/udp/` instead of using `netcat`, but the results were similar.

```
cat test.txt > /dev/udp/239.255.0.2/30002
```

Finally I tried using `awk` to print one line at a time and redirecting that to `/dev/udp`, but the results were really the same.

It appears that both `netcat` and `cat > /dev/udp` both buffer the input until it has a full frame, then sending the frame.  That's not what I want.

Can I flush the udp buffer, or some other way send one UDP message per ^C-delimited message in the source file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
gawk -v 'RS=\03' -v cmd='
  socat -u - udp-datagram:239.255.0.1:30001,bind=127.0.0.1' '
  {print $0 RT| cmd; close(cmd)}' < file
```

should work as long as there's not more than 8k in between two ^Cs.

That runs one `socat` command per *record* (records being ^C delimited via the record separator variable), with the record plus the record terminator fed to `socat` via a pipe.

`socat` reads 8192 bytes at a time, so it's as large a packet it sends can get.

`gawk` writes to the pipe as a full record per write(2).

Using `gawk` instead of `awk` here to make sure it handles NUL bytes properly.

Comment: Brilliant, this seems to work exactly as I want.  Now that I've read about `close` in `gawk`'s manpage, I think I understand how it's working as well.